# Free alternative to Anvil Studio

Tags: windows, gratis, music, music-composing

[Anvil Studio](http://www.anvilstudio.com/) is a free music editor, but it requires paid addons for printing the score. I'm looking for a really free solution that allows me to print scores.

Requirements:

- edit simple scores (piano learner in the first year)

  - treble clef and bass clef
  - full, half, quarter, ... notes
  - dotted notes
  - volume indicators like forte, piano etc.
  - repetitions
- print scores on DIN A4
- play songs during editing
- export songs as WAV or MP3
- Windows 10, but not a store app (I don't have an account and I don't like one, due to the risk of in-app purchases)
- fully gratis, no freemium thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with [MuseScore 2](https://musescore.org/).

- edit scores with everything mentioned before and a lot more
- print scores and export as PDF, PNG and some others
- play songs
- export songs as WAV, MP3 and MID
- works on Windows 10
- is not a Windows store app
- is free ([GPL 2](https://musescore.org/en/about/license-policy))